# What is the meaning of "which are without any traces in the ancient classical heritage"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

- The eighteenth century has gifted English literature two entirely new forms ***which are without any traces in the ancient classical heritage***.

Why is the bolded statement (my bolding) included: what does it mean?

Comment: It just means that these "new forms" don't have obvious classical antecedents.

Comment: It's really a narrowing of the statement in the main clause. If they're entirely new, they can't have traces in any previous works of literature.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Does the statement that the two forms brought have no kind of history or heritage associated with it. They are completely new forms ?

Comment: Yes. Of course 'completely new' has to be seen in context (and I'd wager some Professors of English Literature might not agree with the bold claim). Logicians would argue that unless they're in a new and unrelated language, 'completely new' isn't strictly accurate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth K. Can I reframe the sentence like this “ The eighteenth century …. forms which are completely new ideas & did not have any kind of relation with the history of English literature “ ?

Comment: It sounds clumsy; it's not how I'd word it. But now we're straying off-topic into writing advice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth K , it is just understand if what I understood was correct or not.